# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/tld/TldParser

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

My application worked fine some days ago, but when I execute it today I get the following error:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ContestiOpenDataJungle]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/tld/TldParser
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.<init>(TldScanner.java:86) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.newTldScanner(JasperInitializer.java:120) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:101) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldParser
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
2015-07-24 19:36:41,289 | ERROR | Error deploying web application archive C:\Users\Rosario\Desktop\platform-community-4.1.0\webapps\ContestiOpenDataJungle.war [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig<localhost-startStop-2>] 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ContestiOpenDataJungle]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1880) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

I have tried to change tomcat but it didn't change and now I do not know what the error is.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. 
For more details see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: U will get NoClassDefFoundError, if a class was present during compile time but not available in classpath during runtime. Plz check whether previously available all jars during runtime, are still available. It seems it has overridden somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your pom file and add the jar file of this class org/apache/tomcat/util/descriptor/tld/TldParser to your pom file.
see this link: [add TldParser to pom file](http://www.1maven.com/classname-packaging?pk=org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld&cl=TldParser)

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a dependency problem. you have to use **dependency:tree** to figure it out.
The way it worked for me is to resolve the dependency issue and enable spring boot to debug mode **logging.level.org.springframework = debug**

> focus on tomcat dependency if your project is spring boot + tld

Attaching the sample pom for my project.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-client-hotrod</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-client-hotrod</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
    <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-util-scan</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>${activemq.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.8</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- JSTL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-envers.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- <dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId><version>${hibernate.version}</version></dependency> -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-client-hotrod</artifactId>
    <version>${version.org.infinispan}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- other project dependency - ends -->
```